# Spring boot maven plugin hangs

Tags: maven, spring-boot

We use spring-boot 2.1.5 with spring-boot-maven-plugin to start the package for integration tests. Important parts of our pom look like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
  <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.30.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <images>
      <image>
        <name>postgres:9.6.13</name>
        <alias>app-it</alias>
        <run>
          <ports>
            <port>app.datasource.port:5432</port>
          </ports>
          <wait>
            <log>(?s)database system is ready to accept connections.</log>
            <time>20000</time>
          </wait>
        </run>
      </image>
    </images
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
     <id>prepare-it-database</id>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>start</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>remove-it-database</id>
      <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>stop</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>start</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}</workingDirectory>
          <environmentVariables>
            <app.datasource.port>${app.datasource.port}</app.datasource.port>
           </environmentVariables>
           <profiles>
             <profile>integration</profile>
           </profiles>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
       <execution>
         <id>post-integration-test</id>
         <goals>
           <goal>stop</goal>
         </goals>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
     <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
     <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
       <id>run e2e tests</id>
       <phase>integration-test</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>npm</goal>
       </goals>
       <configuration>
         <workingDirectory>../frontend</workingDirectory>
         <arguments>run verify</arguments>
       </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
 </plugins>
```

Sometimes everything works fine. But sometimes the process just hangs. So I started it with

`mvn -X clean verify`

The result is rather strange as the spring-boot-maven plugin hangs and is  checking the ready state of the spring application only once. All other attemps only follow after hitting Ctrl-C.

```
...
[DEBUG] Active profile(s): integration
[DEBUG] Application argument(s): 
[DEBUG] Environment variable(s): app.datasource.port=16032
[DEBUG] Connecting to local MBeanServer at port 9001
[DEBUG] Waiting for spring application to start...
[DEBUG] MBean server at port 9001 is not up yet...
[DEBUG] Spring application is not ready yet, waiting 500ms (attempt 1)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.5.RELEASE)

2019-06-12 15:34:06.482  INFO 113957 --- [ main] ...: Starting Application on kt101 with PID 113957 ...
...
2019-06-12 15:34:30.801  INFO 113957 --- [ main] ...: Started Application in 24.862 seconds (JVM running for 25.284)
```

The process hangs. Nothing happens. No more messages checking the application state (like attempt 2)

After hitting **[Ctrl-C]**

```
2019-06-12 16:05:02.258  INFO 113957 --- [      Thread-25] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService
[DEBUG] DOCKER> Closing LogWaitChecker callback
[DEBUG] MBean server at port 9001 is not up yet...
[DEBUG] Spring application is not ready yet, waiting 500ms (attempt 2)
[DEBUG] MBean server at port 9001 is not up yet...
[DEBUG] Spring application is not ready yet, waiting 500ms (attempt 3)
...
[DEBUG] MBean server at port 9001 is not up yet...
[DEBUG] Spring application is not ready yet, waiting 500ms (attempt 60)
...
[INFO] backend ................................... FAILURE [33:37 min]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 33:47 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-12T16:06:05+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 238M/6637M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.5.RELEASE:start (pre-integration-test) on project backend: Could not figure out if the application has started: Failed to connect to MBean server at port 9001: Spring application did not start before the configured timeout (60000ms -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.5.RELEASE:start (pre-integration-test) on project backend: Could not figure out if the application has started
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not figure out if the application has started
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.waitForSpringApplication (StartMojo.java:198)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.runWithForkedJvm (StartMojo.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm (AbstractRunMojo.java:284)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:245)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to connect to MBean server at port 9001
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.waitForForkedSpringApplication (StartMojo.java:224)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.waitForSpringApplication (StartMojo.java:187)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.runWithForkedJvm (StartMojo.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm (AbstractRunMojo.java:284)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:245)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Spring application did not start before the configured timeout (60000ms
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.execute (StartMojo.java:277)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.waitForForkedSpringApplication (StartMojo.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.waitForSpringApplication (StartMojo.java:187)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.runWithForkedJvm (StartMojo.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm (AbstractRunMojo.java:284)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:245)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :backend
```

This is rather strange as the spring-boot-maven-plugin seems to hang in the line `synchronized(this.lock)` and can not enter the synchronized block.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/9b5cb4f9b86f258403419a92124a70eb3c099667/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/maven/StartMojo.java#L246

```
            String message = "Spring application is not ready yet, waiting " + wait + "ms (attempt " + (i + 1) + ")";
            getLog().debug(message);
            synchronized (this.lock) {
                try {
                    this.lock.wait(wait);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Interrupted while waiting for Spring Boot app to start.");
                }
}
```

And even more strange: it happens one out of four times I execute this command.

I have two Java Processes running. The original maven process and my Spring Application. I took ThreadDumps of both.

Maven process:

https://pastebin.com/KCfZxDEa

Forked Process with Spring Application

https://pastebin.com/fn0SHjVW

The Spring Application runs fine by the way if I open localhost:8080
The maven plugin seems to hang in the JMXConnection:

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f28dc00b800 nid=0x1e2f runnable [0x00007f28e6865000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    - locked <0x00000006b0963158> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:265)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:222)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.PRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.getAttribute(RMIConnector.java:903)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.SpringApplicationAdminClient.isReady(SpringApplicationAdminClient.java:63)
```

How can I fix this? Why does it happen sometimes and not always?

Comment: Can you take a thread dump of Maven's JVM when it appears to be hung?

Comment: you state you use 2.1.5 but the plugin is spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.3? does the start goal of the plugin work on its own when not part of the build - if you execute it directly?

Comment: Thread Dumps added. Seems to be a JMX problem. And I first wrote the post with 2.1.3 and then updated to 2.1.5 but still had the same problem. So i just changed it in my post manually to 2.1.5 to show that it still exists in the latest version. Sorry for this.

Comment: @Janning did you find a fix for this issue?

Comment: I switched to gradle. This tool is much better. I moved 5 projects within a week and we had some difficult setups with Java processes, aspects, custom plugins.